# How to use FFT algorithm to calculate N-degree polynomial values in N given specific points

Tags: algorithm

This is basically the task i was given on the olympiads in informatic in Poland which is now over. The values should be modulo M (given). Its over now and i know i somehow need to use FFT algorithm to solve it in O(Nlog(N)) complexity.

1. N is a power of 2 (N <= 2^20) and (q^N mod M) = 1;
2. The values are powers from 1 to N of (q) which is given.For example
   when q=5 and N=3, then the output should contain: F(q^1 mod M), F(q^2 mod M),F(q^3 mod M).
3. a1,a2...aN are given in the input (constants in the polynomial)

The brut force would be N^2, and thats too slow. I think the radix-2 algorithm fits perfectly, but i dont know how would it give me the solution as in FFT you use complex numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm you would use is pretty much the same as the FFT, but you use residues mod M instead of complex numbers.  If you add the additional constraints that **M** is prime and all the **q^i** are distinct mod **M**, then you would have a number-theoretic transform:

https://www.nayuki.io/page/number-theoretic-transform-integer-dft

But you don't strictly need those extra constraints to solve your problem.

First, because that 1-based indexing is annoying, I'm going to refer to your **a[N]** as **a[0]** instead, and I'm going to move your **N**th output to the start at index **0**, because it makes the following discussion so much easier.

So you want:

**out[0] = a[0] + a[1] + a[2] ... a[i] ... a[N-1]**

**out[1] = a[0] + a[1]*q + a[2]*q^2 ... a[i]*q^i ... a[N-1]*q^(N-1)**

**...**

**out[j] = ... + a[i]*q^(ij) ...**

Notice that if you have the formula for any **out[j]**, you can make the formula for **out[j]+1** by multiplying the coefficients **a[...]** by **1, q, q^2,...**  So if we have a way to calculate the even-numbered outputs, we can apply it to those modified coefficients to calculate the odd-numbered outputs.

Now, for even-numbered outputs, all the powers of **q** are powers of **q^2**, and they repeat because **q^N = q^0 mod M**.  So, for even numbered outputs, instead of calculating:

**out[j] = a[0] + a[1]*q^j + ... + a[N-1]*q^(j(N-1)) ...**

we can calculate it with half the coefficients like:

**out[j] = (a[0]+a[N/2]) + ... + (a[i]+a[N/2+i])^(q^2)^(ij/2) ...**

And *that* is just the solution to your problem using **q*2** and **N/2** instead of **q** and **N**.

So, just like the (decimation in time version of) FFT, you solve your problem by transforming **a[...]** into two new sets of coefficients, each half the size, and then solve the smaller problem with **q^2** and **M/2** twice using those coefficients to generate the even-numbered and odd-numbered outputs respectively.

I hope that helps... I know it's tough to follow, but if you already understand how the FFT works then you can probably see how to apply it to your problem now.